# change the value of the Grand total from sum of values to average in the matrix visual

Tags: average, powerbi, dax

I have a matrix visual like this attached. Is there any way I could change the grand total to the average value?

Even in the Table view, I still have only the total value, instead, I want the average value to be present at the end of my table.
[image: Matrix Visual]

Any suggestions to get achieve this, please?

PS: I don't want to change my values inside the matrix or tables to change to average and then sum it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

```
Value =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( YourTable[athlete] ),
    SUM ( YourTable[Energy] ),
    AVERAGE ( YourTable[Energy] )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Prakash. This calculates the value for the Energy alone. Should I create a new measure for all the columns like this?  I have 15 more columns to calculate the average, should I calculate for each column?

Comment: Yes Vishnu, a measure for every field you need will be good. There are ways
to use single measure with switch function to select approprate measure but
that may complicate things, for example, to debug where something is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @prakash. I have added separate measures for each columns and put it in a separate table as I wanted. Thanks!